# Pair-wise trimming of files based of max/min values of first/last record

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bit of problem with rather large csv files. I am able to write simple bash/awk scripts, but this problem is harder for my limited awk/bash programming experience.

**Problem:**

- All my files are in folders. Folders have an even number of csv files that need trimming pair-wise (I will explain with this means). Files are named like: f1L, f1R, f2L, f2R, f3L, f3R, ..., fnL,fnR.
- Files need reading in pairs, ie. f1L with f1R. f2L with f2R and so on
- Files have two comma-separated fields. f1L (file start/end) and f1R, look like

> ```
> f1L (START)
> 1349971210, -0.984375 
> 1349971211, -1.000000 
>
> f1R (START) 
> 1349971206, -0.015625
> 1349971207, 0.000000
>
> f1L (END)
> 1350230398, 0.500000
> 1350230399, 0.515625
>
> f1R (END) 
> 1350230402, 0.484375
> 1350230403, 0.515625
> ```

What I would like to do with awk is:

1. Read record 1, field 1 of  f1L (i.e 1349971210) then  record 1, field 1 of f1R (i.e 1349971206). Then take the maximum of both values (i.e x1 = 1349971210).
2. Read last record , field 1 of  f1L (i.e 1350230399) then  last record, field 1 of f1R (i.e 1350230403). Then take the minimum value (i.e x2 = 1350230399).
3. Then extract and re-save with the same name all the lines in f1L and f1R between bigger than/equal to x1 and smaller than/equal x2.
4. Repeat process for all the pairs in my directory.

Wondered if any of you have any suggestions of a little script with bash/awk to get the job done.

Comment: Look at these examples of reading/processing the same file(s) more than once in awk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html , Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A naive way of achieving that in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Not looking for efficiency here at all. No error checkings (well, only the mandatory minimum).

Name this script *myscript*. It will take two parameters (files *fxL* and *fxR*).

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=''

die() {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

on_exit() {
    [[ -f $tmpL ]] && rm -- "$tmpL"
    [[ -f $tmpR ]] && rm -- "$tmpR"
}

last_non_blank_line() {
   sed -n -e $'/^$/ !h\n$ {x;p;}' "$1"
}

(($#==2)) || die "script takes two arguments"

fL=$1
fR=$2

[[ -r "$fL" && -w "$fL" ]] || die "problem with file \`$fL'"
[[ -r "$fR" && -w "$fR" ]] || die "problem with file \`$fR'"

# read record1, line1 of fL and fR
IFS=, read min _ < "$fL"
[[ $min =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || die "first line of \`$fL' has a bad record"
IFS=, read t _ < "$fR"
[[ $t =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || die "first line of \`$fR' has a bad record"
((t>min)) && ((min=t))

# read record1, last line of fL and fR
IFS=, read max _ < <( last_non_blank_line "$fL")
[[ $max =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || die "last line of \`$fL' has a bad record"
IFS=, read t _ < <(last_non_blank_line "$fR")
[[ $t =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || die "last line of \`$fR' has a bad record"
((t<max)) && ((max=t))

# create tmp files
tmpL=$(mktemp --tmpdir) || die "can't create tmp file"
tmpR=$(mktemp --tmpdir) || die "can't create tmp file"

trap 'on_exit' EXIT

# Read fL line by line, and only keep those
# the first record of which is between min and max
while IFS=, read a b; do
    [[ $a =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && ((a<=max)) && ((a>=min)) && echo "$a,$b"
done < "$fL" > "$tmpL"
mv -- "$tmpL" "$fL"

# Same with fR:
while IFS=, read a b; do
    [[ $a =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && ((a<=max)) && ((a>=min)) && echo "$a,$b"
done < "$fR" > "$tmpR"
mv -- "$tmpR" "$fR"
```

and call it as:

```
$ myscript f1L f1R
```

Use it on scratch files first! No warranty! Use at your own risk!

*Caveat.* As the script uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic for comparisons, it is assumed that the first record of each line in each file is an **integer** in the range that [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) handles.

---

**Edit.** Since your first records are floats, you can't use the method above that uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic. A very funny way is to get [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) do all the necessary operations (get first line, last line, open files, …) and use [bc](/questions/tagged/bc) for the arithmetic part. With this, you won't be limited at all with the size of the numbers ([bc](/questions/tagged/bc) uses arbitrary precision), and floats are welcome! For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=''

die() {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

on_exit() {
    [[ -f $tmpL ]] && rm -- "$tmpL"
    [[ -f $tmpR ]] && rm -- "$tmpR"
}

last_non_blank_line() {
   sed -n -e $'/^$/ !h\n$ {x;p;}' "$1"
}

(($#==2)) || die "script takes two arguments"

fL=$1
fR=$2

[[ -r "$fL" && -w "$fL" ]] || die "problem with file \`$fL'"
[[ -r "$fR" && -w "$fR" ]] || die "problem with file \`$fR'"

# read record1, line1 of fL and fR
IFS=, read a _ < "$fL"
IFS=, read b _ < "$fR"
min=$(bc <<< "if($b>$a) { print \"$b\" } else { print \"$a\" }" 2> /dev/null)
[[ -z $min ]] && die "problem in first line of files \`$fL' or \`$fR'"

# read record1, last line of fL and fR
IFS=, read a _ < <( last_non_blank_line "$fL")
IFS=, read b _ < <(last_non_blank_line "$fR")
max=$(bc <<< "if($b<$a) { print \"$b\" } else { print \"$a\" }" 2> /dev/null)
[[ -z $max ]] && die "problem in last line of files \`$fL' or \`$fR'"

# create tmp files
tmpL=$(mktemp --tmpdir) || die "can't create tmp file"
tmpR=$(mktemp --tmpdir) || die "can't create tmp file"

trap 'on_exit' EXIT

# Read fL line by line, and only keep those
# the first record of which is between min and max
while read l; do
    [[ $l =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue
    r=${l%%,*}
    printf "if(%s>=$min && %s<=$max) { print \"%s\n\" }\n" "$r" "$r" "$l"
done < "$fL" | bc > "$tmpL" || die "Error in bc while doing file \`$fL'"

# Same with fR:
while read l; do
    [[ $l =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue
    r=${l%%,*}
    printf "if(%s>=$min && %s<=$max) { print \"%s\n\" }\n" "$r" "$r" "$l"
done < "$fR" | bc > "$tmpR" || die "Error in bc while doing file \`$fR'"

mv -- "$tmpL" "$fL"
mv -- "$tmpR" "$fR"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I keep getting that "bad record" message because my first first field are floats. When I was thinking about the problem I thought bash could do the reading of my files in the directory/find min and max. Then awk.   `for file in $(ls *.csv); do`  # (1) bash to select pair wise files using the x in fxL,fxR (store as $fL and $fR) # (2) bash to find min (x1) and max (x2); (store as $x1 and $x2) # awk does the trimming: `awk -v x1=$x1 -v x2=$x2 '$1>=x1 && $1=<x2' $fR > $fR` (a similar line command for fL) and then `done`

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf. I got it working now. Can't vote your answer unfortunately as I am a new user.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to include all necessary sanity checks and minimize disc-I/O (assuming your files being big enough that reading them is the time limiting factor). Also the files never have to be read in memory as a whole (assuming your files may be even bigger than the available RAM).

However, this was only tried using a very basic dummy input - so please test it and report any problems.

First I wrote a script trimming one pair (identified by the f...L file name):

```
#!/bin/sh

#############    
# trim_pair #
#-----------#############################
# given fXL file path, trim fXL and fXR #
#########################################

#---------------# 
# sanity checks #
#---------------#

# error function
error(){
 echo >&2 "$@"
 exit 1
}

# argument given?
[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || \
 error "usage: $0 <file>"
LFILE="$1"

# argument format valid?
[[ `basename "$LFILE" | egrep '^f[[:digit:]]+L$'` ]] || \
 error "invalid file name: $LFILE (has to match /^f[[:digit:]]+L$/)"
RFILE="`echo $LFILE | sed s/L$/R/`" # is there a better POSIX compliant way?

# files exists?
[[ -e "$LFILE" ]] || \
 error "file does not exist: $LFILE"
[[ -e "$RFILE" ]] || \
 error "file does not exist: $RFILE"

# files readable?
[[ -r "$LFILE" ]] || \
 error "file not readable: $LFILE"
[[ -r "$RFILE" ]] || \
 error "file not readable: $RFILE"

# files writable?
[[ -w "$LFILE" ]] || \
 error "file not writable: $LFILE"
[[ -w "$RFILE" ]] || \
 error "file not writable: $RFILE"

#------------------#
# create tmp files #
# & ensure removal #
#------------------#

# cleanup function
cleanup(){
 [[ -e "$LTMP" ]] && rm -- "$LTMP"
 [[ -e "$RTMP" ]] && rm -- "$RTMP"
}

# cleanup on exit
trap 'cleanup' EXIT

#create tmp files
LTMP=`mktemp --tmpdir` || \
 error "tmp file creation failed"
RTMP=`mktemp --tmpdir` || \
 error "tmp file creation failed"

#----------------------#
# process both files   #
# prepended by their   #
# first and last lines #
#----------------------#

# extract first and last lines without reading the whole files twice
{
 head -q -n1 "$LFILE" "$RFILE"  # no need to read the whole files
 tail -q -n1 "$LFILE" "$RFILE"  # no need to read the whole files
} | awk -F, '
 NF!=2{
  print "incorrect file format: record "FNR" in file "FILENAME > "/dev/stderr"
  exit 1    
 }
 NR==1{                         # read record 1,
  x1=$1                         # field 1 of L,
  next                          # then read
 }
 NR==2{                         # record 1 of R,
  x1=$1>x1?$1:x1                # field 1 & take the max,
  next                          # then
 }
 NR==3{                         # read last record,
  x2=$1                         # field 1 of L,
  next                          # then
 }
 NR==4{                         # last record of R
  x2=$1>x2?$1:x2                # field 1 & take the max
  next
 }
 FILENAME!="-"&&NR<5{
  print "too few lines in input" > "/dev/stderr"
 }
 FNR==1{
  outfile=FILENAME~/L$/?"'"$LTMP"'":"'"$RTMP"'"
 }
 $1>=x1&&$1<=x2{
  print > outfile
 }
' - "$LFILE" "$RFILE" || \
 error "error while trimming"

#-----------------------#
# re-save trimmed files #
# under the same names  #
#-----------------------#

mv -- "$LTMP" "$LFILE" || \
 error "cannot re-save $LFILE"
mv -- "$RTMP" "$RFILE" || \
 error "cannot re-save $RFILE"
```

As you can see, the main idea was to prepend the input by the important lines using `head` and `tail` before processing them using `awk` as you requested.

To call that script for all files in a certain directory, you can use the following script (not as worked-out as the above, but I guess you could come up with something like that yourself):

```
#!/bin/sh

############
# trim all #
#----------###################################
# find L files in current or given directory #
# and trim the corresponding file pairs      #
##############################################

TRIM_PAIR="trim_pair"   # path to the trim script for one pair

if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
then
 WD="$1"
else
 WD="`pwd`"
fi

find "$WD"                         \
 -type f                           \
 -readable                         \
 -writable                         \
 -regextype posix-egrep            \
 -regex "^$WD/"'f[[:digit:]]+L'    \
 -exec "$TRIM_PAIR" "{}" \;
```

Note that you must either have the trim_pair script on your `PATH` or adjust the `TRIM_PAIR` variable in the `trim_all` script.

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];  # directory is argument
my @pairs;
for my $file (glob "$dir/f[0-9]*L") {
    my $n = ($file =~ /(\d+)/)[0];
    my ($fn1, $fn2) = ($file, "f${n}R");
    my ($dL, $dR) = (loadfile($fn1), loadfile($fn2));
    my ($min, $max) = (min($dL->[0][1], $dR->[0][1]),
                       max($dL->[-1][1], $dR->[-1][1]));    
    trimfile($fn1, $dL, $min, $max);
    trimfile($fn2, $dL, $min, $max);
}

sub loadfile {
    my ($fname, @d) = (shift);
    open(my $fh, "<", $fname) or die ("$!");
    chomp, push(@d, [ split(/[, ]+/, $_) ]) while <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    return \@d;
}

sub trimfile {
    my ($fname, $data, $min, $max) = @_;
    open(my $fh, ">", $fname) or die ("$!");
    print($fh $_->[0], " ", $_->[1], "\n") for @$data;
    close $fh;
}

sub min { my ($a,$b) = @_; return $a < $b ? $a : $b; }
sub max { my ($a,$b) = @_; return $a > $b ? $a : $b; }
```